# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this problem.The issue is i am trying to open a doc file in browser,So for that i am converting doc file to Html.This works fine on local. But when i uploads it on live Web server I am getting following error:

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))**
Please look into the matter and help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely not going to work. If you're using Interop, then you need to install MS Office on the server. This is something that is highly recommended not to do. The threading is wrong and MS has been saying not to do this for almost 20 years now.

Comment: Ok I got it.So any suggestion for converting Doc file to HTML, or any other way to open Doc file in browser instead of Downloading.

Comment: There are third-party components that can read .doc files but I don't know of any that are open-source. There is the OpenXML SDK for reading Word 2007+ .docx documents and that's free from MS, but not one for reading .doc. A good example of third-party components for .doc is Aspose software's Aspose.Words component.